# PHP - Echo Groups of 4 Index(s)

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I am pulling information from a text document that has the following information

> Example1, Test, Example1, Test, Example2, Test, Example2, Test,

I am trying to pull information from that document and present it as the following:

> Example1, Test, Example1, Test
>
> Example2, Test, Example2, Test
>
> and so on.......

This is what I have right now of the PHP code as it deplays the message in an array and the index. My goal is to try and print only the first 4 index then break and print the next 4 index and so on. I'm not sure where I should start, so if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$print_data=file_get_contents("http://xxxxxxxxx.log");
$array = explode(',', $print_data);
$length = count($array);
$new_formatted_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    if( ($i + 1) % 4 == 1){
        $new_formatted_array[] = array();
    }
    $new_array_index = count($new_formatted_array) - 1;
    $new_formatted_array[$new_array_index][] = $array[$i];
}

//Just for demo
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_formatted_array);
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Example1
            [1] =>  Test
            [2] =>  Example1
            [3] =>  Test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
Example2
            [1] =>  Test
            [2] =>  Example2
            [3] =>  Test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
Example3
            [1] =>  Test
            [2] =>  Example3
            [3] =>  Test
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

I have used array_chuck which shows the chunk of indexes I want, but it shows array(), [1]array, ect. My end goal is to get the four indexes as a group, but then to be able to format it into a table.

Table:

```html
Example1  Test  Example1  Test
 
Example2  Test  Example2  Test

Example3  Test  Example3  Test
```

Can someone help fix the formatting of the table? Not sure why the rows are not even.

## Figured it out, just not echo print_r

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: can you add  the output of  `print_r($convert);`

Comment: seen array-chunk and slice, but those don't format into a string so I can format it into a table

Comment: @Bluetree ty for the advice I seen that, but my end goal is to format it into a table. With print_r, doesn't it show array and the index?

Comment: yes it display the array the index? does it show to you? can you also add it to your question.

Comment: @Bluetree I did and explain my end goal

Comment: @Bluetree did you just delete the example?

Comment: Yes I just need to edit something. You want it to store the index1 index2 index3 index4 into a single array? Am I correct?

Comment: @Bluetree yes please

Comment: I've undeleted and editted my answer. Try it and tell me if it works

Comment: @Bluetree if my log is in a string, I need to convert into array first?

Comment: Yes. Did you see my answer?. If you can just display the output of this `print_r($convert);`. I can also help you in that problem.

Comment: Array ( [0] =>example1 [1] => test [2] =>example1 [3] => test[4] => example2 [5] => tes [6] => example2 [7] =>tes [8] => ) ; I know this is wrong, ugh. This is my print_1($convert) @Bluetree

Comment: My answer is excactly like this just  replace may `$array` value with your `$convert = explode(',', $print_data); `

Comment: @Bluetree did the changes, the page loaded with error. Assuming there's a synthax error?

Comment: @Bluetree fixed it it works now. If you can help me get it into table format

Comment: @BeginnerScripter I added it in my answer on how to loop and format the table. But if you still didn't fix the problem you can post a new question for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as your basis. I just put a value in array so you can see the output.

```
$array  = array(
     'Example1',
     'Test',
     'Example1',
     'Test',
     'Example2',
     'Test',
     'Example2',
     'Test',
     'Example3',
     'Test',
     'Example3',
     'Test'
);
$length = count($array);
$new_formatted_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    if( ($i + 1) % 4 == 1){
        $new_formatted_array[] = array();
    }
    $new_array_index = count($new_formatted_array) - 1;
    $new_formatted_array[$new_array_index][] = $array[$i];
}

//Just for demo
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_formatted_array);

$output = '<table>';
//Display it in table
foreach($new_formatted_array as $i){
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach($i as $value){
        $output .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}

$output .= '</table>';
//Just for demo
echo htmlentities($output);
```

**New Array output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Example1
            [1] => Test
            [2] => Example1
            [3] => Test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Example2
            [1] => Test
            [2] => Example2
            [3] => Test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Example3
            [1] => Test
            [2] => Example3
            [3] => Test
        )

)
```

**Creating Table output:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Example1</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example2</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Example2</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Example3</td>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Example3</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```